# Java Process, waitFor gives me a 255 exitCode calling a sh file

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a process which should reboot a client from a server.

From my java webapp i reach a controller on the local server

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client/restart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int restartClient(@RequestParam(value = "idClient") int idClient) {
        Client client = clientService.findById(idClient);
        int numeroClient = client.getNumeroClient();
        String command = "/home/pi/park/script/resetClient.sh";
        int exitCode = 1;
        try {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command, "" + numeroClient).start();

            p.waitFor();
            logger.debug("wait for esce con: "+p.waitFor());
            exitCode = p.exitValue();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {

            logger.error("I/O", e);
        }

        return exitCode;

    }
```

this should return the exitCode of the operation. If i call `resetClient.sh`directly from the shell, with its argument, the client gets rebooted correctly.

resetClient.sh it's a simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

CLIENT=$1

ssh client$CLIENT 'sudo /etc/init.d/myscript restart'
```

I have a no password access via ssh between the server and the clients.
My logger returns me `p.waitFor() = 255`
I've tried with command absolute path or relative, but it's the same
If I run the .sh command from the server shell, i get correctly 0

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `ssh` says:

```
ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.
```

It would appear that ssh is failing, but there's not enough information in your post to tell why.
It could be permission related, it could be due to not having a *tty* attached, there's a bunch of plausible reasons.

You really need to capture the output of the command to learn more.

Check `p.getErrorStream()` and `p.getInputStream()`.
There's probably an error message being printed that will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, reading the error stream of the process gave me `ssh: Could not resolve hostname client14: Name or service not known` as launching the script via java does not take in care the ssh config file on the server... Any idea why this happens?

Comment: The most probable cause is that the Java process is running as a different user.